# What would be the best way to document this PHP code?

Tags: php, documentation

Can you tell me what does the function do and how would you document the following function using **Comments**:

```
function tosql($value, $value_type, $is_delimiters = true, $use_null = true) 
    {
        if (is_array($value) || strlen($value)) {
            switch ($value_type) {
                case NUMBER:
                case FLOAT:
                    return preg_replace(array("/,/", "/[^0-9\.,\-]/"), array(".", ""), $value);
                    break;
                case DATETIME:
                    if (!is_array($value) && is_int($value)) { $value = va_time($value); }
                    if (is_array($value)) { $value = va_date($this->DatetimeMask, $value); } 
                    else { return "NULL"; }
                    break;
                case INTEGER:
                    return intval($value);
                    break;
                case DATE:
                    if (!is_array($value) && is_int($value)) { $value = va_time($value); }
                    if (is_array($value)) { $value = va_date($this->DateMask, $value); }
                    else { return "NULL"; }
                    break;
                case TIME:
                    if (!is_array($value) && is_int($value)) { $value = va_time($value); }
                    if (is_array($value)) { $value = va_date($this->TimeMask, $value); }
                    else { return "NULL"; }
                    break;
                case TIMESTAMP:
                    if (!is_array($value) && is_int($value)) { $value = va_time($value); }
                    if (is_array($value)) { $value = va_date($this->TimestampMask, $value); }
                    else { return "NULL"; }
                    break;
                case NUMBERS_LIST:
                case FLOATS_LIST:
                    $values = (is_array($value)) ? $value : explode(",", $value);
                    for ($v = 0; $v < sizeof($values); $v++) {
                        $value = $values[$v];
                        $value = preg_replace(array("/,/", "/[^0-9\.,\-]/"), array(".", ""), $value);
                        if (!is_numeric($value)) {
                            $value = 0;
                        }
                        $values[$v] = $value;
                    }
                    return implode(",", $values);
                    break;
                case INTEGERS_LIST:
                    $values = (is_array($value)) ? $value : explode(",", $value);
                    for ($v = 0; $v < sizeof($values); $v++) {
                        $values[$v] = intval($values[$v]);
                    }
                    return implode(",", $values);
                    break;
                default:
                    $value = addslashes($value);
                    break;
            }
            if ($is_delimiters) {
                $value = "'" . $value . "'";
            }
        } elseif ($use_null) {
            $value = "NULL";
        } else {
            if ($value_type == INTEGER || $value_type == FLOAT || $value_type == NUMBER 
                || $value_type == NUMBERS_LIST || $value_type == FLOATS_LIST || $value_type == INTEGERS_LIST) {
                $value = 0;
            } elseif ($is_delimiters) {
                $value = "''";
            }
        } 
        return $value;
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. It appears to me, that you want someone to write the comments on each line of code, so that you can understand it. Which i fear, very few will even attempt. Else what do you mean by, "how would you document the following function using Comments".

Comment: /* This is while you should comment functions when you write them */

Comment: Put it on the Daily WTF and they'll also tell you everything that is so so so wrong with that :<  ugh.  Somewhere out there, a wheel needs reinventing? You've heard of Bound Parameters, Prepared Queries  and escape right? http://nz.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: @Kent, thanks for the link. Actually the above code is not mine. It is from an application im using. I m trying to understand some functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well giving it a quick once over it appears to be a function to safely convert a given value to a string that can be used in an SQL command. If it can't convert it then it give a suitable safe value, 'NULL', so as not to break the code.

```
usage: tosql( mydate, 'DATE' )
```

Suggest you cut and paste something like the above above the code in a comment...

Answer (score 2):

Using PHPDocumentor

```
/**
 * tosql
 * Converts a string to a valid sql string
 * @param string
 * @param string
 * @return string
*/
function tosql($value, $value_type, $is_delimiters = true, $use_null = true) 
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes a value and a constant denoting the type of value and turns it into something acceptable in a SQL statement. It supports arrays as well for some types (`DATETIME`, `DATE`, `TIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, and `LIST` types). When `$is_delimiters` is true, it surrounds the item with single quotes (for inserted values and comparison tokens that require them).  If `$use_null` is specified, it provides a `NULL` token.

*How* to comment code is a matter of opinion, religion, and how much you care about the next yahoo who has to use your code.